# PstgreSQL WAL archiving wal_size change

Tags: postgresql, wal

I set up in my database WAL archive.
But when I want to set up the WAL file size,

```
min_wal_size = 5MB
and
max_wal_size = 5MB
```

( My database generating one day only 5 MB data so I like to get one WAL file per day )
and restart the server, the server don't start.
If i put back the comment (#) front of the

```
#min_wal_size = 5MB
#max_wal_size = 5MB
```

Then the server run again. I try to use different size ( 2MB 10 MB 100MB ... ) but same issue.
Try to use different minimum of corse smaller ten the max. Not worked.
I try to set up these in cmd also ( ALTER SYSTEM SET... ) way, but same issue.

Somebody have some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min_wal_size` and `max_wal_size` have no connection to the size of a WAL segment. Leave them at their default values.

If you want one WAL segment archived per day, set `archive_timeout = '1d'`.

Comment: Thank you! 
And if I want to set up always 5MB size, What I need to change? wal_segment_size I don't have in my config file, but when I try to add then again not start the server.

Comment: Right, because that doesn't exist. The size of a WAL segment must always be a power of two, and you cannot change it with a parameter. Compress the 16MB WAL segment in the archive, then all those zeros will vanish.